# Powershell set Header on beinning of every C-File

Tags: powershell

I need a dynamic solution approach to this problem:

In Powershell I need to create a script/CMDLET which sets a specific header (Text) on all C-Files.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: What have you tried so far / what's not working for you?

Comment: Hi Manuel, and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is a bit unclear. What characterizes a "dynamic solution approach"? What have you tried so far to achieve your goal? When you say "set a specific header" in a C-file, are you talking about adding `#include` preprocessing statements to a bunch of source files or something else? Are all the files consistently encoded? Please include more details, preferably samples of a file before- and after the intended change

Comment: What I meant by a dynamic solution is that it can be applied on every C-File in a specific directory. Also the header implemented by a #include function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this [module](https://github.com/moerwald/FileHeader_PowerShell/blob/master/FileHeader.psm1), docu is included.

In shorthand it's the following function:

```
function Add-FileHeader {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ })] 
            [string] $DirectoryToSearchThrough,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty ()]
            [ValidateScript({ $_ -ge 1 })] 
            [string[]] $IncludeFilePattern,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [ValidateNotNull()] 
            [string] $FileHeaderToAdd,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
            [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty ()]
            [ValidateScript({ $_ -ge 1 })] 
            [string[]] $ExcludeFilePattern
    )

    Get-ChildItem -Path $DirectoryToSearchThrough -Include $IncludeFilePattern -Exclude $ExcludeFilePattern -Recurse | `
    ForEach-Object {
            Write-Host "Working on $($_.Name)"

            $content = Get-Content $_; 
            Set-Content -Path $_.FullName -Value $FileHeaderToAdd, $content;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.